# Laravel Collection paginate does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

I'm trying to implement basic pagination when retrieving notifications, but I get the following error.

> Method
> Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection::paginate does
> not exist.

```
public function index()
{
    $messages = collect();
    $notifications = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->paginate(5);
    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $message = NotificationToMessageFactory::make($notification->type)
            ->toMessage($notification->data);
        $messages->push($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: That type of `Collection` doesn't have a `paginate` method, however, you can use a [helper function](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-paginate-with-collection-or-arrayexample.html) to achieve this.

Comment: use    ```$notifications = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->paginate(5);```. It will paginate if you have ```unreadNotifications``` relationship defined in modal

Comment: Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.  it returns that and I do have links() in the view, so I'm confused now. I don't either have the relationsip defined in the model, how will that be exactly?

Comment: How is your relationship defined in the User model? and how is the Scope defined?

Comment: Does your User model use the `Notifiable` trait? Make sure the unreadNotifications() method returns a `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instance for paginate to work.

Comment: @CornelRaiu The user model us the notifiable trait. There is no relationship with notifications in the user model, but notifications still work

Answer (score 2):

You've to call paginate() on query builder instance not on  a collection.
Correct syntax will be :

`$notifications = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->paginate(5);`

Comment: I tried that and it returns: Method Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: Did you add the trait on your users model ? 
```use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;```

```...``` 

```use Notifiable```

Also you need to loop through ```$notifications->items()``` rather that ```foreach ($notifications as $notification)``` hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should paginate before looping through the collection, otherwise you will be retrieving all records matching the query, when you only need 5. Like this:

```
$messages = collect();
$notifications = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->paginate(5);
 
foreach($notifications as $notification) {
    $message = NotificationToMessageFactory::make($notification->type)->toMessage($notification->data);
    $messages->push($message);   
}
```

Comment: I updated the post and it's returning a new error: Method Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: I guess you should paginate before retrieving from the database so you don't pull all of them to just display 5 ... that wouldn't make sense. So instead of `user()->unreadNotifications->paginate(5)` you should do: `user()->unreadNotifications()->paginate(5)` to run the paginate on a query builder instance